# Yet another "Failed to validate oauth signature and token"

Tags: scala, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I've this problem that many others have been through. I'm doing everything correct but still i get this annoying "Failed to validate oauth signature and token" error :)

Well, something got to be wrong I guess..

I'm trying to obtain a request_token by making a post to "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token" with headers:

```
Authorization:
 OAuth oauth_consumer_key="MYVq....................ywj2g",
       oauth_nonce="m8NG0s4oc87AOIpuILafAeI1YoMv5Mu9",
       oauth_signature="Bxb%252FFIfOG9KLVj%252FUNdV%252FycVlGPs%253D",
       oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
       oauth_timestamp="1378976842",
       oauth_version="1.0"
```

But it complains about signature and token.
Is my signature invalid somehow?
And for this request I dont need a token right??

I can't figure out whats wrong.

Here's some of my getRequestToken code:

```
val oauth_consumer_key: String      = CONSUMER_KEY
val oauth_nonce: String             = generateNonce()
val oauth_timestamp: String         = (System.currentTimeMillis / 1000).toString
var oauth_signature: String         = ""
val oauth_signature_method: String  = "HMAC-SHA1"
val oauth_version: String           = "1.0"

val PARAMETER_STRING: String =
  "oauth_consumer_key=" + oauth_consumer_key + "&" +
  "oauth_nonce=" + oauth_nonce + "&" +
  "oauth_signature_method=" + oauth_signature_method + "&" +
  "oauth_timestamp=" + oauth_timestamp + "&" +
  "oauth_version=" + oauth_version

val BASE_STRING: String =
  "POST&" + URLEncoder.encode("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "UTF-8") + "&" + URLEncoder.encode(PARAMETER_STRING, "UTF-8")

oauth_signature = getSignature(CONSUMER_SECRET, BASE_STRING, "HmacSHA1")

val AUTHORIZATION = "OAuth " +
  "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(oauth_consumer_key, "UTF-8") +
  "\", oauth_nonce=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(oauth_nonce, "UTF-8") +
  "\", oauth_signature=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(oauth_signature, "UTF-8") +
  "\", oauth_signature_method=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(oauth_signature_method, "UTF-8") +
  "\", oauth_timestamp=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(oauth_timestamp, "UTF-8") +
  "\", oauth_version=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(oauth_version, "UTF-8") + "\""

WS.url("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token").withHeaders("Authorization" -> AUTHORIZATION).post(Results.EmptyContent()).map(response => {
  if(response.status != 200) Logger.error(response.body) //THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
  else {

    if((response.json \ "oauth_callback_confirmed").as[String] == "true") {
      REQUEST_TOKEN  = (response.json \ "oauth_token").as[String]
      REQUEST_SECRET = (response.json \ "oauth_token_secret").as[String]
      requestDone.success(true)
    }
  }
})
```

---

Ok so I've got everyting to work (without the oauth_callback parameter, because if I add this I get the error again).
I get the Request_token, which is valid because when I manually paste the authenticate url in the browser together with the generated request token I get redirected to twitter authenticate page and then a correct callback is made and the result is correct also. (token, token_secret, user_id and screen_name)

But my code seem to ignore my redirect to this authorize page.

```
requestToken_future.map { result =>
      Redirect("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token="+REQUEST_TOKEN)
    }
```

If I put a Logger inside the brackets it shows the log in my terminal window. But that Redirect seems to just be ignored. Never goes off.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the oauth_callback parameter which is required. See the documentation [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/request_token).

Comment: I got it to work. I URLEncoded the signature which caused the error.

Comment: But now when I get to next step, which is to "Redirect the user to Twitter authentication" nothing happens. I have all the correct stuff just before the redirect, but the actual redirect never goes off. I tried to add oauth_callback parameter like you said but that takes me back to square one “Failed to validate oauth signature and token”.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the 'redirect never goes off'. You have to redirect the user yourself to the Twitter oauth/authorize endpoint with the request token as the querystring. Also did you include the oauth_callback parameter in the parameter string when you calculated the signature as well as in the Authorization header?

Comment: I've got everything to work, but only when I manually paste the https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token="+REQUEST_TOKEN in the browser. 

I'll edit my question so you can see more of what I mean.